# Why different outputs come in AppCode from Terminal when using fork()?

Tags: c, fork, appcode

When I try to run an example code about `fork()` I get different output in AppCode than in terminal.

This is one of the functions I tried to use

```
 /*
 * fork3 - Three consective forks
 * Parent and child can continue forking
 */
void fork3()
{
    printf("L0\n");
    fork();
    printf("L1\n");
    fork();
    printf("L2\n");
    fork();
    printf("Bye\n");
}
```

And this is the different outputs I get

**Screenshots:**

Terminal:

[image]

AppCode:

[image]

And this happen to almost all functions in the educational code about `fork()`.

Answer (score 1):

I have not used AppCode, but it looks like it displays only the output of the process that was started from appcode and does not display the output of the forked children. On the other hand on the terminal you get the output for all.

Comment: Yes it seems like that but how to fix it?

Comment: That, unfortunately, I do not know, and a quick google search did not turf up anything... :-(. Good luck finding it out!

Comment: Thank you for your help.